# SelectList with Dictionary, add values to the Dictionary after it's assigned to SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a the following code -

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myDict.Add("keyA", "valueA");
myDict.Add("keyB", "valueB");

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mySelectList = new SelectList(myDict, "key", "value")
```

Further down in the program, I want to add values to `myDict`. Is that possible? If yes, then how?
I want to do something like -

```
mySelectList.myDict.Add("keyC", "valueC");
```

Comment: Yes, you can add values to your dictionary, just like you did.  But do you also want to add them to mySelectList?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to add items to myDict, this is certainly possible, and any changes will be reflected in any of `mySelectList`'s enumerations as long as the changes are made before the enumeration (e.g. using `.ToList()`) is generated.

As a worked example:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        myDict.Add("keyA", "valueA");
        myDict.Add("keyB", "valueB");

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mySelectList = new SelectList(myDict, "key", "value");

        myDict.Add("keyC", "valueC");

        var result = mySelectList.ToList();

      // result is now a list containing three items - keyA, keyB and keyC.

        myDict.Add("keyD", "valueD");

        var result2 = mySelectList.ToList();

      // result2 is a list containing four items. result is
      // unchanged, containing just the original three.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something horrendous like this:

```
((Dictionary<string, string>)mySelectList.Items).Add("keyC", "valueC");
```

It would be better if you just kept the reference to myDict around in your own code, though, rather than abusing their property.

Note: It's very possible this doesn't work. I haven't tried it.